# rake aborted! no such file to load -- html/document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've been trying to get a rake task setup, but when I try to run it, I get

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- html/document
```

The following is the trace for when I try to run rake -T --trace :

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions/response_assertions.rb:2
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions.rb:48:in `included'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions.rb:47:in `each'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions.rb:47:in `included'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions.rb:66:in `include'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/assertions.rb:66
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:1
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/integration.rb:3
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/lib/tasks/update_calls.rake:1
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:142:in `load'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8:in `each'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:8
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/www/phonelog_rb/Rakefile:11
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: WHat is there on /var/www/phonelog_rb/Rakefile:11 ? Perhaps a gem or a lib thats not present? Also what is the rake version?

Comment: rake, version 0.9.2.2
My Rakefile contains

Comment: Whoops:

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
#require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'rdoc/task'

require 'tasks/rails'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a Gem that your application requires isn't present when you're starting the task. Try using `bundle exec rake` and see if that corrects the problem.

Comment: Didn't seem to work.  I tried cleaning up my Gemfile also and removed a few that I'm not using.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rake is unable to find `rdoc/task` or `testtask`. Try adding them to the gem file (eg - gem 'rdoc') and run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/www/phonelog_rb/lib/tasks/update_calls.rake:1
```

It looks like there's something at the top of that file (I'm guessing a `require`) that is causing things to go haywire.